# UICulture List in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, cultureinfo

Where can I find complete UICulture list like en : English en-us etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enumerate all the cultures that are installed on the system by doing this:

```
CultureInfo[] allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
```

You can use the `CultureInfo.Name` property to get the strings like "en-US".

If you're just looking for a web page that lists them all, I found this one:
http://samples.basicdatepicker.com/cultureinfo.aspx

Comment: @Constanta you can use this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219205939/http://samples.basicdatepicker.com/cultureinfo.aspx) to waybackmachine